# Filtering by foreign key in dropdown

Tags: python, django, filter, django-filter

I'm using [django-filters](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html).

My Car model has a Manufacturer foreign key . What I want to do is Filter the Cars by a dropdown that is populated with all Manufacturers in the database.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=5)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
```

My filter currently is a blank text field, you can enter a manufacturer name and then submit to filter this way. The Dropdown would be much more suitable, but I haven't been able to find a way to do this. Here is the filter model as it is now:

```
class CarFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    manufacturer = django_filters.CharFilter(name="manufacturer__name")
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['name', 'manufacturer']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't define the manufacturer filter field *at all* and django-filter will use the default filter for this field (which is a drop down). So something like this should be working:

```
class CarFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['name', 'manufacturer']
```